# Jsonlint validator gives this error Parse error on line 1: varbio={ "name": ^ Expecting '{', '['

Tags: json

```
varbio={
    "name": "Valeriu Turcanu",
    "role": "Front end web Developer",
    "image": "path to image",
    "skills": [
        "Html",
        "Css",
        "Javascript",
        "Python",
        "Jquery"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not JSON.

That is an assignment of a js object to a variable named `varbio`

the json would be

```
{
    "name": "Valeriu Turcanu",
    "role": "Front end web Developer",
    "image": "path to image",
    "skills": [
        "Html",
        "Css",
        "Javascript",
        "Python",
        "Jquery"
    ]
}
```

---

If you were, instead, just trying to declare a variable then you might have missed a space after the `var`

```
var bio={
    "name": "Valeriu Turcanu",
    "role": "Front end web Developer",
    "image": "path to image",
    "skills": [
        "Html",
        "Css",
        "Javascript",
        "Python",
        "Jquery"
    ]
}
```

But this has nothing to do with JSON.